# Drawing a rectangle behind a button makes the button not work (CSS)

Tags: html, css, button

I'm new to CSS and I'm having some problems with it. Right now I'm trying to draw a rectangle behind two buttons, and while I've had some success at drawing the rectangle that renders the buttons useless. Here's the code I've made for the nav in the html (where the buttons are located):

```css
body {

    background-color:mediumspringgreen;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: 30% 6% 60% 4%;
    grid-template-areas:    "header"
                            "nav"
                            "main"
                            "footer";

}


.rectangle{

    width: 100%;

    height: 4%;

    background: gold;

    position: absolute;

    display: flex;

    z-index: -1;

    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}

.button1{

    background-color: green;

    color: gold;

    border: 3px solid mediumspringgreen;

    border-radius: 12px;

    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;

}

nav{

    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

}
```

```html
<nav>
    <p class = "rectangle">
        <button class = "button1" onclick="location.href= 'pàgina%20productes.html'">Productes</button>
        <button class = "button1" onclick="location.href= 'pàgina%20contacte.html'">Contacte</button>
    </p>
</nav>
```

Does anyone know any solution to make the buttons clickable? If I remove the rectangle I can go to the button's link, it only happens when there's the rectangle behind them.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: It seems to fail only when there are more tags than nav inside the body. Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h0uw36dk/

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue. With what you have shown right now, the buttons are clickable perfectly fine, when I run your snippet in a Chromium-based browser.

Comment: It's working. Even when you Click on Run code snippet. Can you provide with more details?

Comment: Sorry, I've seen that if you remove all parts except the nav one it works for some reason. Here's the full JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h0uw36dk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem with z-index. You don't need to add `z-index` property in rectangle.

```
.rectangle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 4%;
    background: gold;
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that made the trick! I thought I needed the z-index to put the rectangle on the background.